# I can't allocate memory for this struct

Tags: c, struct

I've this struct and function:

```
typedef struct{

       char *maze_size;
       char *trophy;
       int time_max;
       char *moves;

}gameHistory;
```

The function receives the pointer `gameHistory *gameHistoryReaded` to reserve memory, but don't work.

```
void loadGameHistory(char fileName[], gameHistory *gameHistoryReaded, int *statusCode){
       /*  Here send error  */
       *gameHistoryReaded = (gameHistory*)malloc(LENGTH_GAME_HISTORY*sizeof(gameHistory));
       (*gameHistoryReaded).maze_size = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
       (*gameHistoryReaded).trophy = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
       (*gameHistoryReaded).moves = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));

       FILE *file = fopen(fileName,"rb");
       char line[200];
       char *token1;
       if (file == NULL){
            printf("\nError de lectura: archivo no encontrado\n");
            *statusCode = 0; //Si se presenta algun error en la lectura del archivsetea en 0 (error)
            exit(1);
        }
        fgets(line,200,file);
        token1 = strtok(line,":");
        strcpy((*gameHistoryReaded).maze_size, token1);
        token1 = strtok(NULL,":");
        strcpy((*gameHistoryReaded).trophy, token1);
        token1 = strtok(NULL,":");
        strcpy((*gameHistoryReaded).moves, token1);
        token1 = strtok(NULL,":");
        (*gameHistoryReaded).time_max = atoi(token1);

        fclose(file);

}

int main(){

        char routegameHistory[] = "game_history.txt";
        int statusCode = 1;
        gameHistory gameHistory;

        loadGameHistory(routegameHistory, &gameHistory, &statusCode);

 }
```

Code::Blocks shown me this:

error: incompatible types when assigning to type '`gameHistory`' from type '`struct gameHistory *`'

But I think the `struct` are well declared,
other point,
 I allocate memory for the `int time_max`?

Comment: Ok, I tried an answer, but after reading your other posts, I **strongly** recommend to take a proper programming/C course (e.g. read a good book). You should get the basics right first. This will also help not being downvoted on every question and incerases chances to get an answer to-the-point. No offense!

Answer (score 2):

`gameHistory gameHistory;` is an error. A typename cannot be re-used as a variable name. Let's assume you meant:

```
gameHistory history;
```

This allocates memory already. You do not need to allocate any extra memory. Simply remove the attempted `malloc` line from your function and all will be well.

However, further down in your function there would be a problem:

```
strcpy((*gameHistoryReaded).maze_size, token1);
```

So far you have not made `maze_size` point anywhere, so you cannot copy characters to it. You could either make `maze_size` be a char array (in which case it would not require any more allocation), or you could allocate space and point to that space:

```
gameHistoryReaded->maze_size = strdup(token1);
```

The `strdup` function does `malloc` and `strcpy` in one go.

The same problem occurs with `trophy` and `moves`; and finally you should check `token1 != NULL` each time.

Answer (score 1):

You dereference the pointer gameHistoryRead, which yields the struct. To assign the result of malloc to the pointer itself, just dont dereference (omit the `*`).

Why do you pass this pointer to the function anyway? It is overwritten instantly. If you intend to return the malloc'ed struct to the caller, you need a pointer to the pointer (`**gameHistoryRead`). In this case, the first line would be correct, as you are assigning to the pointer itself.

Just noticed: you paas the struct already, so why did you malloc it? That makes just no sense (I suppose now you wanted to fill the passed struct, but why the malloc then?).

Just remove the malloc() of the struct completely or have a look at the code below.

However, this is bad design. It would be better to return a pointer to the malloc'ed struct, NULL on error (see code blow). Note that the caller **must** check the result before accessing the returned struct.

Also, you forgot to free() the malloc'ed blocks in the error-case. Remember to free() **all** allocated memory, not just the first struct.

You also forgot to set statuscode in case of success (if passing the struct to be filled, it was better to return the status code, not use a pointer to it).

The malloc size of the struct is wrong. `sizeof(...)` already yields the correct size (unless you want to return an array, but then even more is wrong).

In main(): You cannot use the same name for a variable as for a type (and you should not even think about just changing the case - this hinders readability); see main().

Sidenotes:

- Do not cast a `void *` as you do for the result of malloc(). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for an explanation.
- Check the result of malloc before using. It can be NULL (no memory available). Dereferencing a NULL-pointer results in undefined behaviour (UB). This means anything can happen (it can even pass unnoticed).
- Do not use (*p).m to access a member of a struct from a pointer. Instead, use `->` which has exactly been designed for this.
- If the other fields (`maze_size`, ...) always have a constant size, why not simply use arrays (with constant size), avoiding malloc for each? This makes cleanup *much* easier.

A better approach would be:

```
gameHistory *loadGameHistory(char fileName[])
{
    bool error = false;
    gameHistory *hist =
            malloc(sizeof(gameHistory));
    if ( hist == NULL )  return;  // fail instantly

    hist->maze_size = malloc(MAX_STRING); // sizeof(char) is 1 by standard)
    error |= hist->maze_size == NULL;

    // alloc further blocks

    // here do what you want. set error = true on error and skip rest

    // finally:
    if ( error ) {
        // out of memory: free all other blocks
        free(hist->maze_size);    // if NULL, free does nothing (standard)

        // ...

        free(hist);
        return NULL;
    }

    return hist;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion (in the first para) would not work anyway because the pointer is a local variable to the function; so the caller would not see the allocated memory (which is clearly the intention)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yeah, I edited my answer as I saw more and more problems. However, I alaready suspected in the second paragraph. Last I saw was that he is actually passing the struct to the function, so it is completely unclear why he malloc'ed the struct anyway. I always get a bit nostalgic seeing such code. Although I would have been happy to have something like SO (or Internet) back then.

Answer (score 0):

`gameHistoryReaded` is a pointer to `gameHistory` structure.

This line:

```
   *gameHistoryReaded = (gameHistory*)malloc(LENGTH_GAME_HISTORY*sizeof(gameHistory));
```

assigns the valued returned from `malloc()` to whatever `gameHistoryReaded` points to.

Probably not what you want.

Don't dereference the pointer with `*`.